# Force IE to work in standards mode

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, doctype, ie-compatibility-mode

I was working on JQchart. It works fine on mozilla and chrome. When I run it on any versions of IE it automatically goes in quirks mode and doesn't display anything to me.

But when I change mode to Standard from developers tools in IE it works fine

So what I should do to make it work in IE standard mode

I have already tried the following things

1. `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >`
2. `<!DOCTYPE html>`
3. `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >`

but nothing from above helped.

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri i tried it in IE8 and IE 9

Comment: exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220711/classic-asp-page-automatically-sets-quriks-mode-as-defualt-in-ie-8 , I think the top voted answer may clear your problem

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara...tried all the solution from the link..didnt help at all

Comment: @nikhil your meta tag must be the first tag inside your head tag. I had this problem, I read this recommendation, and it works!

Comment: @TiagoBrenck..i tried it..did not work

Comment: Does JQChart use an `iframe`? or are you using on a site embedded in an iframe?  IE has an unfortunate issue whereby the mode of the outermost window object forces that mode (standards or quirks) on the documents `iframe`'d in it.